# Android 4.4 Kitkat and second external storage

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-4.4-kitkat

There has been written a lot about Kitkat external sdcard write permission but it's not clear to me how it works. Unfortunately I don't have Kitkat device with sdcard slot. Question is, can I write to secondary external storage at all? Based on [the docs](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/storage/).

> Apps must not be allowed to write to secondary external storage
>   devices, except in their package-specific directories

If in understand it, If I don't have permission I can write to the app specific folder on primary external storage `/sdcard/Android/data/package/...` and to the app specific folder on secondary external storage `/extSdcard/Android/data/package/...`

and with `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` I can write to all locations on primary external storage `/sdcard/*` but I can't write to any location on secondary external storage (except app specific folder)?

Thanks for all answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your analysis is correct, other than assuming that primary external storage is `/sdcard` (the exact path varies by device, OS level, and user account for Android 4.2+ tablets).

Here are some blog posts that I wrote recently on [external storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) and [removable ("secondary external") storage](http://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html).

Comment: You can also use EnvironmentCompat and ContextCompat to get the paths and statuses of the various external storage components. However, I have no idea how to know for sure if there is a real, removable SD-card or not. Also, I have no idea in which case this is wrong: Environment.isExternalStorageEmulated()==(!Environment.isExternalStorageRemovable()) .

Comment: so that means apps like whatapp store their images and videos in primary storage and this path is accessible via `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` ?

Comment: @hadi: Sorry, I am not a whatapp user.

Comment: @CommonsWare well i meant whatsapp not whatapp :)

Comment: @hadi: I don't use WhatsApp either. Whether they use internal or external storage, I cannot say.

Answer (score 0):

I know this topic is old but this may help. You should use this method.

```
System.getenv();
```

see project [Environment3](https://github.com/omidfaraji/Environment3) to access all storage that is connected to your device.

https://github.com/omidfaraji/Environment3