# Detect removable external storage in Android

Tags: android, storage

As I know, there are 3 kinds of storage,

1. **Internal Storage**: Its private and no one can access to it. 
   For 
   example:`File internalFile = new File(getFilesDir(), "MyFile.txt");`
2. **External Storage**: It is not removable.
   For 
   example: `File externalFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "MyFile.txt");`
3. **Secondary External Storage**: It can be mounted or unmounted by the user.

My question is for third type of storage. How can I access to secondary SD card? I have searched for hours but I did not find the answer.

Comment: [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23199954/android-kikkat4-4-and-second-external-storage). As it is, your question is a bit too broad and lacking in detail.

Answer (score 0):

To detect sd card availability you can do it on this way

```
    boolean mExtStorage = false;
    boolean mExtWriteable = false;
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        mExtStorage = mExtWriteable = true;
    } else if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
        mExtStorage = true;
        mExtWriteable = false;
    } else {
        mExtStorage = mExtWriteable = false;
    }
```

Comment: I`d like to save somthing in < Secondary SD Card > , Would you give me one example ?

Comment: this link might be helpful http://www.java-samples.com/showtutorial.php?tutorialid=1523

Answer (score 0):

There are only 2 types,

1. **Internal Storage**
2. **External storage**, which can be removable (SD card) or non-removable.

Check [this guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal) for more details. I hope it has all that you need.

You can detect the storage state, as specified in the guide, using the following code

> ```
> /* Checks if external storage is available for read and write */
> public boolean isExternalStorageWritable() {
>     String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
>     if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
>         return true;
>     }
>     return false;
> }
>
> /* Checks if external storage is available to at least read */
> public boolean isExternalStorageReadable() {
>     String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
>     if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state) ||
>         Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(state)) {
>         return true;
>     }
>     return false;
> }
> ```

Comment: how to detect if external storage is removable or non-removable?!